# Bound of the gradient of a $C^{m}$ function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f$ be a $C^{m}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ function, that is a function which is $m$ times continuously differentiable. Is it true that $$ |\nabla f(x)| \leq  \frac{C}{|x|^{n}}$$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $C>0$?

I think this is true due to the fact that each component of $f$ is integrable because of being the derivative  of $f$ and $g(x)=1/|x|^{n}$ isn't integrable in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ but I can't write this in a rigurous way.

Edit: I can take extra assumptions: $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $f(ax)=a^{-n+1}f(x)$.

Thank you.

Comment: you seem to be missing some assumptions, take $e^x$ for a counterexample

Comment: Dear @Taggy, I might be missing something but if $n=1$, then this states that $\left|f'(x)\right|\leq \frac{C}{\left|x\right|}$ for all $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and some constant $C$ (depending on $f$). In particular, $\lim_{\left|x\right|\to \infty} \left|f'(x)\right|=0$ but I don't think this is true for all $C^1$ functions - e.g., $f(x)=x^2$. or mm-aops great counterexample.

Comment: Thank you both, you are right. I can also take the assumption that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $f(ax)=a^{-n-1}f(x)$ (for $a>0$). Is is true in this case?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be: $f(ax)=a^{-n+1}f(x)$ in my last comment

Comment: OK, I've solved it. From the last assumption one can find a similar equality for partial derivatives and then one can write $x = |x| \theta(x)$ (where $|\theta(x)|=1$) and use this assumption and the fact that the derivative is bounded in $\{ x \in R^{n} : |x|=1 \}$